# ReactJS Passing Data Between Components (search bar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone Im doing a search bar using react and got a program, before I was passing data between components parent > child, child > parent but now I need to pass from my src>components>toolbar>search bar to src>containers>category component, someone could help me?? thankss

Comment: What is the relationship between the two components (their instances, not the source files)?

Comment: you would either need to pass them all the way back up to the shared parent and them back down to the other child, or implement redux or something similar

Comment: The relationship is the root( app component ), I was thing in something like pass all the way back but I gonna take a look in  redux, thanks guys, appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this, by creating and dispatching an event and listing this in a component.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.nv.addEventListener("custom-event", this.handleNvEnter);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
this.nv.removeEventListener("custom-event", this.handleNvEnter);
}

handleNvEnter = (event) => {
 console.log("custom-event:", event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your question and the first thought that came to my mind was introducing Redux.

You can do this by installing a few packages using npm.

- Redux (core library for Redux) [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/)
- React-Redux (Redux is a apart from React and needs this package to work cohesively) [React usage with Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact)

Honestly I could ramble on and tell you how to integrate every little detail. But I'm not going to do that instead I'll give you an overview of how you would use this technology to your benefit. Be warned this is going to require a bit of time to master, however in doing this your ability to design complex systems will be greatly enhanced.

1. Firstly, you're going to want to learn a bit more about how Redux stores and data. Here is an introductory course by Dan Abramov the creator of Redux [Redux course](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux). It isn't too long and is free!
2. Once you're familiar with stores, reducers, action creators, actions and the Provider component --->Close your laptop<--- and take out a pen and paper and map the hell out of what belongs where. For instance, your search data belongs in a reducer that handles it, and your going to have to design your actions accordingly too plus read their payloads and map them to the store.
3. Now code it. With the design being completed and necessary information on how to develop with redux, this should be a stroll in the park.

Hope this helps your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve that problem is to use Redux (https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) which is typically used for storing the values and which you can use it throughout the application files.

The below links will help you understand Redux and how to implement to your react application: 
https://github.com/bradtraversy/redux_crash_course

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM&t=537s

https://github.com/bradeac/using-redux-with-react/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data up to the topmost parent and then pass it down again to the child you want to.